# Joining 4 tables together mysql (getting many duplicate values)

Tags: mysql, database

I want to join 4 database tables together. Each of the tables have have the studenId field in common and all the other fields are different. 
I want to have something like this

studentId|beginTime|endTime|audioText|sentiment|bpm|long|lat|movementcoordinates|

These fields should be filled in on the basis of the values from the other table.

This is the code I have tried

```
USE signals_db;
INSERT INTO trainingTable
SELECT audio.beginTime, audio.endTime, audio.audioText, audio.sentiment,
heartrate.bpm, locations.long, locations.lat,
movements.gravityX, movements.gravityY, movements.gravityZ,
movements.accX, movements.accY, movements.accZ, movements.rotX,
movements.rotY, movements.rotZ,
movements.attRoll, movements.attPitch, movements.attYaw, movements.fallenDown
FROM audio
    INNER JOIN heartrate
    ON audio.studentId = heartrate.studentId
    INNER JOIN locations
    ON audio.studentId = locations.studentId
    INNER JOIN movements
    ON audio.studentId = movements.studentId
```

With the above code a lot of duplicate values will be created in the joined table. 
And I tried several answers already but most of things do not work.

I hope you can help me out.

Here is the picture of the joined table:

[image]

Comment: Why are there duplicates?

Comment: There are a bunch of duplicates. I actually do not know why this problem occurs.

Comment: If you don't know it - then this should be your question. Before you start to fix symptoms of something you don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If really you obtain duplicated  rows

You could use DISTINCT for obtain on a single rows  for each duplciated

```
SELECT DISTINCT audio.beginTime, audio.endTime, audio.audioText, audio.sentiment,
    heartrate.bpm, locations.long, locations.lat,
    movements.gravityX, movements.gravityY, movements.gravityZ,
    movements.accX, movements.accY, movements.accZ, movements.rotX,
    movements.rotY, movements.rotZ,
    movements.attRoll, movements.attPitch, movements.attYaw, movements.fallenDown
    FROM audio
        INNER JOIN heartrate
        ON audio.studentId = heartrate.studentId
        INNER JOIN locations
        ON audio.studentId = locations.studentId
        INNER JOIN movements
        ON audio.studentId = movements.studentId
```

Comment: So, with distinct it would be possible to avoid the issue of duplicated values in a row like I have mentioned in the picture?

Comment: if the  content of the rows  are enterly duplicated  DISTINCT remove the duplicated   rows  and return only a single row for each duplicated .   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Comment: Thank you very much. That's what I need. I will test it tomorrow directly.

Comment: I would recomend to check where those duplicates cames from. If there shouldn't be any duplicates it is a sign you have an error in some other place. `DISTINCT` will look like it works but there could be errors. Check if there are other relateions between joined tables.

Comment: The studentId appears several times in each of the tables since the data come from a wearable device. Every time the user turn off the device a new studentId will be created. But that shouldnt be an issue I guess. I will try it out directly tomorrow

Comment: DISTINCT probably only hides the problem in this case - it's not a solution.